# Is it a good idea to add a column to the posts table?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, table

I'm making a custom theme for a client who has need of two custom post types. I'd like to join them together (it's a one-on-many connection) and thus was thinking of adding a column to the posts table to store the connection.

Of course I've read that I could use the posts_meta table to store extra info about some posts but to be fair, it feels like a roundabout way to do it, especially if you could just store the information in a column.

So I was wondering if adding a column to the standard wp posts table was a good idea or no.

Comment: the answer is "no"

Comment: Could you at least elaborate why not, @MarkKaplun?

Comment: A new table entirely with the connection would be better.

Comment: in general, changing internals of software that you didn't write, where the software did not explicitly declare to support such a change, is always a bad idea unless you are happy to maintain a fork.

Comment: I'd rather recommend using taxonomies or Posts 2 Posts for that instead of altering the posts table in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another column wouldn't break the code at all .. but it might create issues while updating WordPress to a new version ..

It's better to add another table having fields (`ID` PK Auto Increment, `post_id` FK, `<your-custom-column>`) .. the `post_id` field will point to `ID` field in `wp_posts` table as a foreign key!